# Trouble getting measurments of my circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, low-pass, multisim, passive-filter

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

[image: Results]

I'm trying to turn the first image in a multisim circuit but i can't get the right measurements. I have tried a vcc power source but i still can't get the right result in the oscilometer can anyone give me an pointers because i'm new in multisim?

Comment: Looks like you're plotting a graph in the time domain, instead of the frequency domain. What units are you currently using, and what units do you want to use instead?

Comment: I honestly don't know what units will help me i tried a vcc power source and now i tried an ac power source based on a recommendation from a friend. I don't now how to properly plot in the frequency domain. I only have the pictures as a reference point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There is an error showing V+=Vcc (U1-7) power connected to an input node.

Since this circuit uses a 0V reference  with R4 to 0V, it needs a bipolar supply.

2) V- = Vee (U1-4) is open on schematic and needs some negative supply.

**This is why you have no output signal.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have done an transient analysis, do an AC sweep ( I don't know what version of multisim you have but here are instructions for the [latest version](https://www.multisim.com/help/simulation/grapher/ac-sweep/))

An AC sweep will allow you to get an amplitude vs frequency plot.

If you still want to find dB, you can do this for a transient plot, you need to know the amplitude of voltage in and voltage out, then calculate dB

\$   dB = 20*\log_{10}\frac{Vout}{Vin}\$

Comment: THis is not the solution to make it function, but may be useful info.